# updating gradle version for a project that depends on another shared library project doesn't work in a toolchain (kubernetes)

Tags: java, gradle, kubernetes

I'm getting this error while trying to commit my changes into gitlab repo and deploy it in kubernetes after upgrading gradle version to 7.4

Also I think the problem in how I include my shared library inside the project it self, that's what I sense from the error output below

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':distTar'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :vlc-shc.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching configuration of project :vlc-shc was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':vlc-shc')
    }
```

setting.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'vlc-myProject'
include ('vlc-shc')
```

Comment: The question is weird. You don't commit something into kubernetes. Explain what are you doing...

Comment: sorry for this. I edited the post, mainly I upgraded project gradle to latest version locally and I'm trying to deploy the project into k8s deployment, but this issue I see while toolchain is running

Comment: I realized two things. Filename must be settings.gradle and the include should not contain colons.

Comment: Done and I'm still seeing the same issue ..